# Getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError" and a lot of errors

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I'm really new to programming, and I'm working on a java assignment for school and I know That i got most of the code I've written wrong, but it's the first time I've really attempted anything like this.

I'm trying to trouble shoot, but i get the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
>
> at a07.Time.(Time.java:27)
>
> at a07.Time.(Time.java:27)
>
> at a07.Time.(Time.java:27)

This continues for quite some time.

I was hoping someone could tell me the cause of the problem so i could start fixing.

```
    Public class Time {

        private int hour;
        private int minute;
        public static final int MIN_HOUR = 0;
        public static final int MIN_MINS = 0;

        public Time(int hours, int mins) {
            minute = mins;
            hour = hours;
            Time t = new Time(hour, minute);
            t.fixME();
        }

        private void fixME() {
            int minEx = minute / 60;
            int minLeft = minute % 60;
            int newHour = hour + minEx;

            minute = minLeft;
            hour = newHour;

        if (minute < MIN_MINS) {
            int subHour = hour - 1;
            int minNew = minute + 60;
            hour = subHour % 24;
            minute = minNew;

            if (hour < MIN_HOUR) {
                int hourUp = hour + 24;
                hour = hourUp;
            }
        }
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return hour;
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return minute;
    }

    public Time addMinutes(int mins) {
        int newMinute = minute + mins;
        minute = newMinute;
        Time g = new Time(hour, mins);
        return g;

    }

    public void print() {
        if (hour == 0) {
            System.out.printf("12:" + "%02f", minute + " AM");
        }
        if (hour != 0 && hour < 10) {
            System.out.printf("0" + hour + ":" + "%02f", minute + " AM");
        }
        if (hour >= 10 && hour < 12) {
            System.out.printf(hour + ":" + "%02f", minute + " AM");
        }
        if (hour >= 12) {
            int pmHour = hour - 12;
            if (pmHour == 0) {
                System.out.printf("12:" + "%02f", minute + " PM");
            } else if (pmHour < 12) {
                System.out.printf(pmHour + ":" + "%02f", minute + " PM");
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Sorry it's not formatted very well.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: dont do this in your constructor `Time t = new Time(hour, minute);`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your constructor:

```
public Time(int hours, int mins) {
    minute = mins;
    hour = hours;
    Time t = new Time(hour, minute);
    t.fixME();
}
```

You're calling the constructor again with the line `Time t = new Time(hour, minute)`, so you're stuck in an infinite recursive loop where you keep calling the function over and over again until your stack overflows. You don't actually need this line; you can just do the following:

```
public Time(int hours, int mins) {
    minute = mins;
    hour = hours;
    fixME();
}
```

I don't think you fully understand how objects and constructors work though, you should probably try going through this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/